# Apollo/GraphQL SSO authentication using Kerberos or NTLM

Tags: graphql, kerberos, apollo

Has anyone authenticated a client using Windows integrated security from an Apollo Client? Any tips or pointers would be much appreciated

Comment: I haven't seen anything on this.  A quick web search brought up essentially nothing which would help you.  This doesn't answer the question but is at least remotely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44509832/how-to-set-up-apollo-client-only-after-user-authenticates

Comment: Thanks. I have been trawling the net and found nothing either. Thanks for the link. I saw that too so may need to start exploring some of those concepts

Comment: The logic is explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13949163/windows-integrated-authentication-in-node-js-client/13960538#13960538 so now the challenge is to code it

Comment: Microsoft has a Graph API which is rumored to use Windows integrated security.   Would that work?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `credentials: 'include'` in the HttpLink seems to be enough (at least with Edge, on a Windows 11 domain box):

```
const httpLink = createHttpLink({
    uri: 'http://localhost:8080/graphql',
    credentials: 'include'
})

const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
    link: from([httpLink]),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
})
```

It's a bit magically how this actually works in practice: without adding in that setting the server responds with a HTTP 401, and `WWW-Authenticate: NTLM` header; adding in the setting I don't actually see the auth flow in the debug tools, just the final authenticated request/response.